# SPSS Last available measurement in a row of variables

Tags: spss

I am looking how can I get the last available measurement in a row of variables.

The dataset looks like:

var1 var2 var3 var4 var5... var100

25   30   11   .    .       .

30   .    .    .    .       .

44   15   22   35   16      24

.    .    31   27   .       .

I would like to identify the last available variable with a value in each row. Please let me know if I can do that without restructuring the selected variables into cases.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Copy-paste-run this entire syntax without having any data open for a demo.

```
data list free/v1 v2 v3 v4.
begin data
1 '' '' ''
1 2 '' ''
1 2 3 ''
1 2 3 4
end data.

do repeat v = v1 to v4.
if not missing(v) last_valid = v.
end repeat.
exe.
```

For the first valid value, you could use something like the syntax below. Note that there's an alternative that's computationally faster (using `loop` and `break`) but that requires some more code. If the code below takes a lot of time to complete, I'll write the fast version for you but let's first try the simple solution.

```
data list free/v1 v2 v3 v4.
begin data
'' '' '' 4
 '' '' 3 4
'' 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
end data.

numeric first_valid.
do repeat v = v1 to v4.
if not missing(v) and missing(first_valid) first_valid = v.
end repeat.
exe.
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I also tried to apply it to find the first available measurement in the row, but it seems like different approach is needed :) Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: Please mark the answer as "accepted" if it solved your problem. I'll add a version for the first valid value below.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answer! It helped me to go in a right direction. I ended up with the alternative code for computation of the first valid measurement in a row using loops as you suggested.

Last available measurement in a row of measurements:

```
DEFINE last_valid ()
!DO !@ = 1 !TO 100.
!LET !a=!CONCAT("v",!@). 
COMPUTE last_valid = !a.
!DOEND.
!ENDDEFINE.
last_valid.
EXECUTE.
```

First available measurement in a row:

```
DEFINE first_valid ()
!DO !@ = 1 !TO 100.
!LET !a=!CONCAT("v",!@). 
LOOP IF missing(first_valid) = 1.
COMPUTE first_valid = !a.
END LOOP IF first_valid > 0.
!DOEND.
!ENDDEFINE.
first_valid.
EXECUTE.
```